# Creating DAL for ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-access-layer

I am working on Microsoft Visual Studio `DAL` in which I am doing the traditional method of fetching/updating the data to show the reviews of the listed items of website by retrieving data from the `ItemDetails` table of the website database, for creating the `ItemDetails.aspx` file. I added a `DropDownList Control` to displaying all items within its categories. 
On selection of category from Drop-down list, it shows all items within that category, with a hyperlink attached `"Show Details"` to it to show details in a grid-view.
i am newbie i have no idea to create `DAL` for asp.net website. Need easy guidelines to create DAL for asp.net website. Help will be appreciated. What are the other ways to create DAL rather than `SQLadapter`.

Comment: I personally use the Entity Framework Code-First (I define my tables as classes with strongly-typed references). It generates the Db dynamically and then I use the repository pattern to query eg... `User user = UserRepo.Single(x=>x.Username=="Bob");` Throw in the `UnitOfWork` pattern for saving changes and it's a really elegant and relatively efficient ORM. Note that the one major drawback is that bulk updates can be slow - when you're updating hundreds of thousands of records at once, it's easier to drop back to a Sql adapter.

Comment: i want to use it for website has nearly 15-17 pages and 60 database tables.

Comment: That's not really an issue. I've used it on a site with ~100 tables and hundreds of pages. The only reason bulk updates are an issue is that they're not sent to SQL in batches - eg it does `UPDATE A set B=C WHERE Id = 1`, `UPDATE A set B=C WHERE Id = 2`, etc. instead of `UPDATE A set B=C WHERE Id IN (1,2)` but unless you're performing the same update to thousands of rows simultaneously, it's not an issue

Answer (score 1):

So for example here is a DAL I've used before for calling SPs.

It allows you to execute stored procedures and return dataset, datatables, success responses etc.

**Really it depends on how you intend to access the data**, will you be writing Stored Procedures or will you have queries in your code. You also have the option of using Entity Framework/LINQ.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public class _DataInteraction
{

    #region "Stored Procedures"

    public static DataTable stdReturnDataTableQuery(string procedureName, string db)
    {
        DataTable myDataTable;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        cmd.CommandText = procedureName;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = myConnection;


        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // make our datatable to return
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        myDataTable = new DataTable();

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // fill the datatable with the stored procedure results
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //flag as error happened
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            if ((myDataAdapter != null))
                myDataAdapter.Dispose();
            if ((cmd != null))
                cmd.Dispose();
        }

        return myDataTable;
    }


    //   Return a datatable from the database
    public static DataTable stdReturnDataTable(string procedureName, List<SqlParameter> myParameters, string db)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = default(SqlConnection);
        SqlCommand myCommand = default(SqlCommand);
        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = default(SqlDataAdapter);
        DataTable myDataTable = default(DataTable);
        string connString = null;

        //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //   create instance of connection
        //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString;
        myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString;

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //   create instance of command and dataadapter
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        myCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureName, myConnection);
        myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //   say its a stored procedure command
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //   add any parameters?
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        if ((myParameters != null))
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter myParm in myParameters)
            {
                // add the parameter to the command
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(myParm);
            }
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // make our datatable to return
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        myDataTable = new DataTable();

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // fill the datatable with the stored procedure results
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //flag as error happened
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            if ((myDataAdapter != null))
                myDataAdapter.Dispose();
            if ((myCommand != null))
                myCommand.Dispose();
        }

        return myDataTable;
    }

    //   Return a dataset from the database
    public static DataSet stdReturnDataset(string procedureName, List<SqlParameter> myParameters, string db)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = default(SqlConnection);
        SqlCommand myCommand = default(SqlCommand);
        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = default(SqlDataAdapter);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string connString = null;

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //   create instance of connection
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString;
        myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString;

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //   create instance of command and dataadapter
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        myCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureName, myConnection);
        myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //   say its a stored procedure command
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //   add any parameters?
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        if ((myParameters != null))
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter myParm in myParameters)
            {
                // add the parameter to the command
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(myParm);
            }
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // fill the datatable with the stored procedure results
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //flag as error happened
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            if ((myDataAdapter != null))
                myDataAdapter.Dispose();
            if ((myCommand != null))
                myCommand.Dispose();
        }

        return ds;
    }

    //   Return success from a query from the database
    public static bool db_NonQuerySuccessResponse(string strCommandText, List<SqlParameter> myParameters, string db)
    {
        SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand SQLCommand = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string Value = "";
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            SQLCommand.CommandText = strCommandText;
            SQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SQLCommand.Parameters.Clear();

            if ((myParameters != null))
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter myParm in myParameters)
                {
                    // add the parameter to the command
                    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(myParm);
                }
            }

            SQLCommand.Connection = SQLConnection;
            SQLConnection.Open();
            SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SQLConnection.Close();

            success = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
            return success;
        }

        return success;

    }

    //   General non query, no results no success
    public static bool db_NonQuery(string strCommandText, List<SqlParameter> myParameters, string db)
    {


        SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand SQLCommand = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            SQLCommand.CommandText = strCommandText;
            SQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SQLCommand.Parameters.Clear();

            if ((myParameters != null))
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter myParm in myParameters)
                {
                    // add the parameter to the command
                    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(myParm);
                }
            }

            SQLCommand.Connection = SQLConnection;
            SQLConnection.Open();
            SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SQLConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    ////   Execute scalar on db
    //public static string db_Scalar(string strCommandText, ref List<SqlParameter> myParameters, string db)
    //{

    //    SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString);
    //    SqlCommand SQLCommand = new SqlCommand();
    //    string Value = "";

    //    SQLCommand.CommandText = strCommandText;
    //    SQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //    SQLCommand.Parameters.Clear();


    //    if ((myParameters != null))
    //    {
    //        foreach (SqlParameter myParm in myParameters)
    //        {
    //            // add the parameter to the command
    //            SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(myParm);
    //        }
    //    }

    //    SQLCommand.Connection = SQLConnection;
    //    SQLConnection.Open();
    //    Value = SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar;
    //    SQLConnection.Close();
    //    return Value;
    //}

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is 1 sample for reference............

```
        public List<T> GetRequests(string strNo)
    {
        List<T> objlstMapping = null;
        Mapping objMapping = null;
        try
        {
            Database objDbInstance = CreateSQLDatabase(DbConnection.MF);

            using (DbCommand objDbCommand = objDbInstance.GetStoredProcCommand(Constants.SP_QUESTS))
            {
                DALBase.AddDbParam(objDbInstance, objDbCommand, "@No", DbType.AnsiString, ParameterDirection.Input, strFolioNo);

                objDbCommand.Connection = objDbInstance.CreateConnection();
                objDbCommand.Connection.Open();
                using (DbDataReader dr = objDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    objMapping = new List<T>();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            objMapping = new BrokerFolioMapping();
                            objMapping .Brok_Code = SProposedValue(dr, "Code");
                            objMapping .Active = SProposedValue(dr, "Status");
                            objMapping .AccStmt_Active = SProposedValue(dr, "PortfolioStatus");

                            objlstFolioMapping.Add(objMapping );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                        }
        return objlstFolioMapping;
    }
```